# How to know which columns contain only zeros in R?

Tags: r

I currently have a data frame with columns that contain many zeros but also some columns with positive values.

**How can I know the columns that contain ONLY zeros?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you column numbers that have only 0's.

```
which(colSums(df==0) == nrow(df))
#b 
#2
```

Another way to write this is -

```
which(colSums(df != 0) == 0)
```

Or, to find out how many columns have zeros (TRUE) or don't (FALSE)

```
table(colSums(df != 0) == 0)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 0), b = 0, c = c(0, 0, 0, 1))
```

Comment: acutally, I'm looking for to have in result the name of the column and TRUE or FALSE, TRUE if ALL values within the column are equal to 0

Comment: @TristanUbaldi Then no need to use `which` - `colSums(df != 0) == 0`

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks, but I also wonder if there is a function to know the number of columns where the result is TRUE or FALSE? e.g, on 10 column in tot, 3 FALSE and 7 TRUE

Comment: `table(colSums(df != 0) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     select(where(~ all(. == 0)))
```

-output

```
b
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
```

To do the reverse, i.e. remove those columns

```
df %>%
    select(where(~ any(. != 0)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 0), b = 0, c = c(0, 0, 0, 1))
```